# Add text for specific position in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am parsing data from API and i  would like to add text for specific position in RecyclerView. For example : Add "ABC" text for Position "3" in Gini TextView.
How can i do it? Thanks in advance

[image]

**BindViewHolder**

```
  final JsonMain pozycja = filtr.get(position);


    holder.country_flag.setImageResource(pozycja.getLogo());
    holder.country_name.setText(pozycja.getName());
    holder.country_subregion.setText(pozycja.getSubregion());
    holder.country_nativename.setText(pozycja.getNativeName());
    holder.country_capital.setText(pozycja.getCapital());
    holder.country_topleveldomain.setText(pozycja.getTopLevelDomain().get(0));
    holder.country_population.setText(String.valueOf(pozycja.getPopulation()));
    holder.country_gini.setText(String.valueOf(pozycja.getGini()));
    holder.country_area.setText(String.valueOf(pozycja.getArea()));
```

Comment: Can't you just set "ABC" to the TextView instead of a value from json? you can add a condition if position == 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```java
final JsonMain pozycja = filtr.get(position);
        holder.country_flag.setImageResource(pozycja.getLogo());
        holder.country_name.setText(pozycja.getName());
        holder.country_subregion.setText(pozycja.getSubregion());
        holder.country_nativename.setText(pozycja.getNativeName());
        holder.country_capital.setText(pozycja.getCapital());
        holder.country_topleveldomain.setText(pozycja.getTopLevelDomain().get(0));
        holder.country_population.setText(String.valueOf(pozycja.getPopulation()));
        holder.country_area.setText(String.valueOf(pozycja.getArea()));

        if (position == 3) {
        holder.country_gini.setText("ABC");
        }   
         else {
         holder.country_gini.setText(String.valueOf(pozycja.getGini()));

    }
}}
```

If position is not in 3, the text returns to `String.valueOf(pozycja.getGini()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't change "0.0" to "ABC" in 3 position.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want ?
And what is your variable ?